# Redirecting to local post route

Tags: laravel, redirect, post, guzzle

### Short version

Do we need GuzzleHttp to redirect to **local POST route**? Can't we do this directly using `redirect()`?

### Long version

Following [this Laravel tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGh0cKEVXPI) about using Passport authentication, the presenter talks about a way of hiding `client_id` to increase security (check at around 11:45 in the video).

The idea is to expose a new wrapper route that accepts only `username` and `password` fields and then the controller injects `client_id` on the server-side and makes a new call to Passport's original login route. This call is made using GuzzleHttp client. Response of the call is then returned by the wrapper route to the caller.

My question is: Do we really need to install and use Guzzle? Can't we redirect to Passport's login route using `redirect()` or some other built-in Laravel function?

Answer (score 0):

You need Guzzle to make a HTTP request so that you can modify the response before sending it.

You will not be able to hide any data using `redirect()` because it will just tell the browser (client) to use the passport route directly.

To avoid making the HTTP a call you could get your route to run the code that the passport route runs and then modify the response that is generated. Making a local HTTP call should not be a problem though.

Comment: Questions: 1. As far as I see, the presenter wants to modify the request, not the response. Or did I miss something?, 2. Can't I block direct access to passport route on the server-side?